# Configurations for charging batteries of varying voltage from one source for RV

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lifepo4

I have wired up a solar system in my travel trailer, using a 7s1p 48V (58.7V) pack from used Nissan Leaf battery modules. I am now making a 12 volt battery from a bunch of LiFePO4 18650 cells I have from dead tool batteries as a backup battery, so the basic appliances still run if the inverter kills the main battery (all batteries are wired correctly with a BMS).

I am trying to figure out the best and safest way to charge the small battery and also connect it, so the batteries charge using shore power and the truck while traveling.

Originally, I wanted to have the trailer's converter boosted to 58.7V into the big battery, then that bucked to 15V from the big battery for the little one. The problem is that the converter's output is also the DC input for the trailer, so wiring it like this would make a loop between the batteries.

My first thought is to solve this with analog relay circuits that reroute, depending on whether the converter is putting out or not. I came here to ask if this is unwise, because it seems like it would work but is also a little risky.

Comment: I hope you chose balanced cells . Used batteries tend to have at least 1 bad cell-thus charging, discharging will overstress that cell

Comment: They are. Each tool batt has one bad cell, they actually blew one almost first use with a jigsaw. I'd say the brand but not sure if that's allowed here.

Comment: And the nissan leaf modules were professionally paired.

Comment: A BMS with CC CV and cutoff is advised

Comment: Yes; as I said they are wired with proper bms boards. My question is about the safety of the configuration I am proposing.

Comment: Though it is a serious matter so thanks for looking out.

Comment: With BMS LV detection, for both Bats. the small buck charger shud not pose an issue.

Comment: I see what you mean there, but what about if the relay circuts fails (though unlikely I think) leaving the small battery boosted to 58.7 and the big batt bucked to 15? Would batteries just continue to charge each other or would this make the wires heat up and start a fire? I suppose it would kill one of the buck/boost converters first. And it would be fused.

Comment: I plan on making the relay circuts as fail-proof as possible, I am just being as precautious as possible.